# How to prevent a user from taking a screenshot in Ionic/Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Is it possible to prevent the user from taking a screenshot in an android application developed using Ionic/Cordova?

If it's possible, How?
I asked in the Ionic forum but i did not get an answer there.

Comment: Why are people down voting this??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with a plugin.  Use the one here:
http://blog.devgeeks.org/post/92139782094/the-privacy-screen-plugin-for-cordova-phonegap

Note however, there is no completely fool proof way of stopping people from capturing what you display.  They can always point another camera at the phone for example, or if they root the phone they can bypass the security.

Comment: Have you used it? After reading the plugin info, it looks like it has nothing with preventing the user from capturing the screen. It just places a black image instead the a screenshot of the app when switching apps in the android.

Comment: Yes, here is the pertinent documentation for Android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE

By setting FLAG_SECURE, it prevents both the task switchers and the screenshot / screen recording.

Comment: Forgot to add, if you are using CrossWalk you will have to modify it (or modify CrossWalk) since a different window is created for CrossWalk and this plugin does not take that into account.

Comment: Ok i will give it a try

Comment: @BradL. thanks.... that link shown me a way to my solution. Thank you very much.