# How to prevent a user from taking a screenshot in Android Crosswalk WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I'm trying to prevent from taking a screenshot in Crosswalk WebView. I have tried [PrivacyScreenPlugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/PrivacyScreen). This plugin works very good when I wasn't using Crosswalk plugin. However, if I added Crosswalk plugin, it only works at the app launch time.
For example, when I launch my app, I can not take a screenshot. However, if I show any other UI component (such as volume control, etc..), my app start allowing to take a screenshot.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040235/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-taking-a-screenshot-in-ionic-cordova) related question and one person mentioned that if I use Crosswalk, I need to modify PrivacyScreenPlugin/Crosswalk.

Here is what I tried:
In Crosswalk WebView plugin, XwalkWebViewEngine#init method.

```
cordova.getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

However, above code wasn't fix my issue.
And, I couldn't find a place to modify in PrivacyScreenPlugin.

I'm using following Android versions and plugins:

- Android 5.0.2
- Crosswalk plugin 1.6.1
- PrivacyScreenPlugin 0.2.0

Any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-5091?focusedCommentId=38097&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-38097) ticket. There is a temporary workaround to avoid this issue.

In AndroidManifest.xml:
Replace

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"

with

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: Sadly, the Crosswalk team has marked it `Resolved` with resolution `Won't Fix`, so the workaround isn't so temporary anymore :-( That said, at least this solution still works as of Crosswalk 22.

Comment: As Crosswalk is no longer maintained as of version 23, this has now also become the only work-around for preventing screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround worked for me. It basically digs to the SurfaceView that XWalkView creates and makes it secure:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    ((SurfaceView)((FrameLayout)((FrameLayout) mXWalkView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setSecure(true);
}
```

Looks ugly but worked like a charm.