# How to Prevent Screen Capture in Android/Ionic 2 framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have restricted the screen capture and recording in android using the below code snippet. It is working fine in same application but i want to redirect the app to some other page(Payment page) where user should not see the payment page(here user can able to see the page). How do i restrict those pages not to record?

The following code added in **onCreate** method of **ManActivity.java** file

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a user from taking a screenshot in Ionic/Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040235/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-taking-a-screenshot-in-ionic-cordova)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217232/how-to-disallow-screenshoot-in-ionic-3